# Bot Framework Handoff Scenario to live person on MS Teams

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, handoff

We have a bot that we have deployed to Azure using SDK4. We are looking for a simple scenario to handover a bot conversation to a physical person on a MS Teams chat channel.
I can't find a simple project that explains how to add a Teams channel, and how to configure and trigger the handoff protocol.
Any ideas ?

Comment: did you find a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-faqplus it has a handoff flow smilar to what you are looking for